# Is there any wrap object class, that you get from IEnumerable? (ItemsSource in TreeView)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

### Main aim

I want to make my own UserControl in WPF, based on TreeView. My aim is to make so, to have the opportunity to change SelectedItem from code.

### One way to solve

In MVVM pattern you can make "IsSelected" property in TreeItemViewModel and bind "IsSelected" in ItemContainerStyle like this:

XAML:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

TreeItemViewModel:

```
private bool _isExpanded;
public bool IsExpanded { get { return _isExpanded; } set { _isExpanded = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded"); } }
private bool _isSelected;
public bool IsSelected { get { return _isESelected; } set { _isSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); } }
```

By doing like this, you can watch through all your ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> that you bind to ItemsSource, find needed element and change "IsExpanded" and "IsSelected" for it's parents.

### What I want

I want my UserControl to have all this bindings inside it. My UserControl will inherits from TreeView, and I will make my own MyItemsSource that will take IEnumerable (like the original ItemsSource in TreeView). In my point of view, next stage of my plan is to wrap objects from IEnumerable, in new class that will have two more properties: IsSelected and IsExpanded. And then to bind this properties inside my UserControl.

### Why I want this

Due to this in my future projects i want to be able not two add this two properties and change SelectedItem from code.

### Main Question

How Can I wrap objects that I get from IEnumerable (without knowing class that i get, because it is UserControl) in new class with two additional properties?

### More explanations

UserControl class:

```
public partial class UserControl : TreeView
    {
        public UserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public System.Collections.IEnumerable MyItemsSource
        {
            set
            {
                ObservableCollection<UserControlTreeItemViewModel> ItemsSourceWrapped = new ObservableCollection<UserControlTreeItemViewModel>();

                // wrap objects in cycle
                foreach(var item in value)
                {
                    ItemsSourceWrapped.Add(new UserControlTreeItemViewModel(item));
                }

                this.ItemsSource = ItemsSourceWrapped;
            }
        }

    }
```

And class to wrap objects:

```
public class UserControlTreeItemViewModel : Object
    {
        public UserControlTreeItemViewModel(object i)
        {
            // How to write constructor to wrap object that you get?
        }

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
    }
```

Main question: Is there any way to wrap objects that you get from IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0):

This is the base ViewModel class that I use for data items to be displayed in a TreeView control. It handles things like the child item collection, expansion, selection, checking (tick box) including updating parent and child items, disabled state, lazy loading of child items.

```
public class perTreeViewItemViewModelBase : perViewModelBase
{
    // a dummy item used in lazy loading mode, ensuring that each node has at least one child so that the expand button is shown
    private static perTreeViewItemViewModelBase LazyLoadingChildIndicator { get; } 
        = new perTreeViewItemViewModelBase { Caption = "Loading Data ..." };

    private bool InLazyLoadingMode { get; set; }
    private bool LazyLoadTriggered { get; set; }
    private bool LazyLoadCompleted { get; set; }
    private bool RequiresLazyLoad => InLazyLoadingMode && !LazyLoadTriggered;

    // Has Children been overridden (e.g. to point at some private internal collection) 
    private bool LazyLoadChildrenOverridden => InLazyLoadingMode && !Equals(LazyLoadChildren, _childrenList);

    private readonly perObservableCollection<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> _childrenList 
        = new perObservableCollection<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase>();

    /// <summary>
    /// LazyLoadingChildIndicator ensures a visible expansion toggle button in lazy loading mode 
    /// </summary>
    protected void SetLazyLoadingMode()
    {
        ClearChildren();
        _childrenList.Add(LazyLoadingChildIndicator);

        IsExpanded = false;
        InLazyLoadingMode = true;
        LazyLoadTriggered = false;
        LazyLoadCompleted = false;
    }

    private string _caption;

    public string Caption
    {
        get => _caption;
        set => Set(nameof(Caption), ref _caption, value);
    }

    public void ClearChildren()
    {
        _childrenList.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new child item to this TreeView item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="child"></param>
    public void AddChild(perTreeViewItemViewModelBase child)
    {
        if (LazyLoadChildrenOverridden)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't call AddChild for an item with LazyLoad mode set & LazyLoadChildren has been overridden");
        }

        if (_childrenList.Any() && _childrenList.First() == LazyLoadingChildIndicator)
        {
            _childrenList.Clear();
        }

        _childrenList.Add(child);
        SetChildPropertiesFromParent(child);
    }

    protected void SetChildPropertiesFromParent(perTreeViewItemViewModelBase child)
    { 
        child.Parent = this;

        // if this node is checked then all new children added are set checked 
        if (IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            child.SetIsCheckedIncludingChildren(true);
        }

        ReCalculateNodeCheckState();
    }

    protected void ReCalculateNodeCheckState()
    {
        var item = this;

        while (item != null)
        {
            if (item.Children.Any() && !Equals(item.Children.FirstOrDefault(), LazyLoadingChildIndicator))
            {
                var hasIndeterminateChild = item.Children.Any(c => c.IsEnabled && !c.IsChecked.HasValue);

                if (hasIndeterminateChild)
                {
                    item.SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    var hasSelectedChild = item.Children.Any(c => c.IsEnabled && c.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault());
                    var hasUnselectedChild = item.Children.Any(c => c.IsEnabled && !c.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault());

                    if (hasUnselectedChild && hasSelectedChild)
                    {
                        item.SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(hasSelectedChild);
                    }
                }
            }

            item = item.Parent;
        }
    }

    private void SetIsCheckedIncludingChildren(bool? value)
    {
        if (IsEnabled)
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));

            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                if (child.IsEnabled)
                {
                    child.SetIsCheckedIncludingChildren(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(bool? value)
    {
        _isChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add multiple children to this TreeView item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="children"></param>
    public void AddChildren(IEnumerable<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> children)
    {
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            AddChild(child);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove a child item from this TreeView item
    /// </summary>
    public void RemoveChild(perTreeViewItemViewModelBase child)
    {
        _childrenList.Remove(child);
        child.Parent = null;

        ReCalculateNodeCheckState();
    }

    public perTreeViewItemViewModelBase Parent { get; private set; }

    private bool? _isChecked = false;

    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set
        {
            if (Set(nameof(IsChecked), ref _isChecked, value))
            {
                foreach (var child in Children)
                {
                    if (child.IsEnabled)
                    {
                        child.SetIsCheckedIncludingChildren(value);
                    }
                }

                Parent?.ReCalculateNodeCheckState();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isExpanded;

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get => _isExpanded;
        set
        {
            if (Set(nameof(IsExpanded), ref _isExpanded, value) && value && RequiresLazyLoad)
            {
                TriggerLazyLoading();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isEnabled = true;

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get => _isEnabled;
        set => Set(nameof(IsEnabled), ref _isEnabled, value);
    }

    public void TriggerLazyLoading()
    {
        var unused = DoLazyLoadAsync();
    }

    private async Task DoLazyLoadAsync()
    {
        if (LazyLoadTriggered)
        {
            return;
        }

        LazyLoadTriggered = true;

        var lazyChildrenResult = await LazyLoadFetchChildren()
            .EvaluateFunctionAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        LazyLoadCompleted = true;

        if (lazyChildrenResult.IsCompletedOk)
        {
            var lazyChildren = lazyChildrenResult.Data;

            foreach (var child in lazyChildren)
            {
                SetChildPropertiesFromParent(child);
            }

            // If LazyLoadChildren has been overridden then just refresh the check state (using the new children) 
            // and update the check state (in case any of the new children is already set as checked)
            if (LazyLoadChildrenOverridden)
            {
                ReCalculateNodeCheckState();
            }
            else
            {
                AddChildren(lazyChildren); // otherwise add the new children to the base collection.
            }
        }

        RefreshChildren();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the children for this node, in Lazy-Loading Mode
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual Task<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase[]> LazyLoadFetchChildren()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new perTreeViewItemViewModelBase[0]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update the Children property
    /// </summary>
    public void RefreshChildren()
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Children));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// In LazyLoading Mode, the Children property can be set to something other than
    /// the base _childrenList collection - e.g as the union ot two internal collections
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> Children => LazyLoadCompleted
                                                                ? LazyLoadChildren
                                                                : _childrenList;

    /// <summary>
    /// How are the children held when in lazy loading mode.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Override this as required in descendent classes - e.g. if Children is formed from a union
    /// of multiple internal child item collections (of different types) which are populated in LazyLoadFetchChildren()
    /// </remarks>
    protected virtual IEnumerable<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> LazyLoadChildren => _childrenList;

    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            // if unselecting we don't care about anything else other than simply updating the property
            if (!value)
            {
                Set(nameof(IsSelected), ref _isSelected, false);
                return;
            }

            // Build a priority queue of operations
            //
            // All operations relating to tree item expansion are added with priority = DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, so that they are
            // sorted before any operations relating to selection (which have priority = DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle).
            // This ensures that the visual container for all items are created before any selection operation is carried out.
            //
            // First expand all ancestors of the selected item - those closest to the root first
            //
            // Expanding a node will scroll as many of its children as possible into view - see perTreeViewItemHelper, but these scrolling
            // operations will be added to the queue after all of the parent expansions.
            var ancestorsToExpand = new Stack<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase>();

            var parent = Parent;
            while (parent != null)
            {
                if (!parent.IsExpanded)
                {
                    ancestorsToExpand.Push(parent);
                }

                parent = parent.Parent;
            }

            while (ancestorsToExpand.Any())
            {
                var parentToExpand = ancestorsToExpand.Pop();
                perDispatcherHelper.AddToQueue(() => parentToExpand.IsExpanded = true, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
            }

            // Set the item's selected state - use DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle so this operation is executed after all
            // expansion operations, no matter when they were added to the queue.
            //
            // Selecting a node will also scroll it into view - see perTreeViewItemHelper
            perDispatcherHelper.AddToQueue(() => Set(nameof(IsSelected), ref _isSelected, true), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);

            // note that by rule, a TreeView can only have one selected item, but this is handled automatically by 
            // the control - we aren't required to manually unselect the previously selected item.

            // execute all of the queued operations in descending DispatcherPriority order (expansion before selection)
            var unused = perDispatcherHelper.ProcessQueueAsync();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Caption;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// What's the total number of child nodes beneath this one
    /// </summary>
    public int ChildCount => Children.Count() + Children.Sum(c => c.ChildCount);
}
```

IsExpanded and IsSelected are then bound to the TreeViewItem's properties in a global style.

```
<Style
    x:Key="perTreeViewItemContainerStyle"
    TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />

    <!--  Link the properties of perTreeViewItemViewModelBase to the corresponding ones on the TreeViewItem  -->
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />

// ....

</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource perTreeViewItemContainerStyle}" />
</Style>
```

You can then make a wrapper class for each model item type that you want to display in a TreeView. for example

```
public class PersonTreeViewWrapper: perTreeViewItemViewModelBase
{
    public PersonTreeViewWrapper(Person model)
    {
        Model = model;    
    }

    public Person Model {get;} 
}
```

I would not try to make this wrapping hidden inside the control, but instead publish a nested collection of PersonTreeViewWrapper items in the ViewModel to be bound as the ItemsSource of the TreeView.

One reason for this is if you want to have multiple item types displayed in the same TreeView control, you have to be able to specify the HierarchicalDataTemplate to be used for each item type.

```
<TreeView
    Grid.Column="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding RootItemVms}">

    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type vm.PersonTreeViewWrapper}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Focusable="False"
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="4,0,8,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding Model.DisplayName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

You can also add a bindable SelectedItem property to a TreeView control using a Behavior class.

```
public class perTreeViewHelper : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    public object BoundSelectedItem
    {
        get => GetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundSelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundSelectedItem",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(perTreeViewHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                OnBoundSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnBoundSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewValue is perTreeViewItemViewModelBase item)
        {
            item.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object obj, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> args)
    {
        BoundSelectedItem = args.NewValue;
    }
}
```

You can get more details of these classes and their usage on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/).

Comment: Dear Peregrine, thanks for your answer, you have very good TreeItemViewModel)  
But my question was about getting rid of properties IsSelected and IsExpanded from TreeItemViewModel. I want to put this properties inside UserControl, based on TreeView.

Comment: @LK1nn Those properties beling to invidual items rather than the TreeView as a whole, so they have to be stored somewhere ... might as well make it explicit how you're doing that.

Comment: I Add some explanations to the question and will be greatful if you answer, is it possible to do so)

Comment: I've already given what I believe to be the best way to handle displaying data in a TreeView control in a WPF / MVVM context. I don't understand what you think you would be gaining by hiding the implementation of the item wrapping inside your user control.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have chosen the wrong direction to find a solution to your problem.
The TreeView name is a bit misleading.
A tree can only have one vertex and must not have cycles. That is, all the nodes (Item) in the tree are unique.

Check out the typical use of a TreeView in Windows Explorer: multiple entry points and the same file or folder may be on different branches.
Hence, simply setting the SelectedItem is not enough to select the item.
You need to provide the full path to the item.

To solve your problem, I would recommend that you create not your own UserControl, but create an Attached Property (let's say  SelectItem) for the TreeView passing the path to the selected item.

You can specify the path in different ways: a list of items at the top, a string with a path, and other variants.
In the Attached Property logic, when the value changes, the path will be parsed and traversed through the TreeView Visual Dynamic Tree with the selection and expansion of the required nodes.